# Is __COUNTER__ macro portable?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a piece of code which uses `__COUNTER__` macro to generate unique names for variables.

Is this code portable ? I know that GCC and MSVS support it. What's about other compilers ? Is the macro defined by standard (as far as I know before C++14 it wasn't).

Comment: It'd help to provide answers that are useful to you if you could give a little insight into the range of compilers you care about....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's definitely **not** standard.

It's a compiler extension ([GNU C extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html))

> The common predefined macros are GNU C extensions.

and a [Microsoft-specific one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx),

> Microsoft-Specific Predefined Macros:
>
> __ COUNTER __

also supported by [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html) as language extension.

[The standard doesn't mention it anywhere](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).

Comment: IAR C/C++ Compiler (for AVR) supports it as well

Answer (score 3):

GCC manual, section [Common Predefined Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html), states

> The common predefined macros are GNU C extensions.

I've also never seen this macro in the C99, C11 or C++11 standards.

As for practical portability: [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html) supports it, too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems **NO**. When I ctrl+f "__COUNTER__" on [standard pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), I couldn't find anything >o<