# C define macro that expands not the same when not used for the first time

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to write:

```
#define FIRST_DEF 1
#define SECOND_DEF 2    

#ifndef ALREADY_DEFINED
#define MY_MACRO FIRST_DEF
#define ALREADY_DEFINED
#else
#define MY_MACRO SECOND_DEF
#endif
```

So that MY_MACRO does not have the same value when not used the first time?

So that writting:

```
int a = MY_MACRO;
int b = MY_MACRO;
```

expands to:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
```

If not, is there a way to do this?
(I know that this example is silly but it is just to make the question clearer.)

Comment: You mean that in a single file you want `MY_MACRO MY_MACRO` to expand into `FIRST_DEF SECOND_DEF`?

Comment: Does the code you posted doesn't work? Can't it be just `#ifndef MY_MACRO` `#define MY_MACRO SECOND_DEF` `#endif`?

Comment: If a macro is redefined with a definition that is not effectively the same as the old one, the preprocessor issues a warning and changes the macro to use the new definition

Comment: @StoryTeller I have editted my question to answer you

Comment: Can you explain why you would need such behavior ? (ideally in a specific use case) It would help us figure out how best to answer this.

Comment: I guess thats not possible. You expand the macro twice and not define it twice.

Comment: I would say that even trying to do stuff like this with macros is pretty bad practice.

Comment: lets remember that macros (`#define` statements) are simply text replacement actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example, you can use the pre-defined macro `__COUNTER__` which will get incremented everytime it is used. Note that it is a non-standard compiler extension, but both GCC and MSVC support it.

Comment: Thanks @user3804799, and is it widely supported?

Comment: I know for sure that GCC and MSVC support it for a long time as I worked on projects that used it. I can't talk about clang, but there is a SO question about this and it seems that it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160235/is-counter-macro-portable

Answer (score -2):

Yes. I think it is OK.

```
#include "xxx.h"
// FIRST_DEF here
#include "xxx.h"
// SeCOND_DEF here
```

But you must include the header twice

Comment: This will not work because `#define MY_MACRO SECOND_DEF` redefines `MY_MACRO` in violation of C 2018 6.10.3 2: “An identifier currently defined as an object-like macro shall not be redefined by another `#define` preprocessing directive unless the second definition is an object-like macro definition and the two replacement lists are identical.”

Comment: Really? But I see both gcc and clang treat it as Warning @EricPostpischil